# How to define default options to a class?

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options

I do not undestand how to pass options to the parent class when writting a child class. I tried several possibilities but I never get flush left aligned equations.

I do understand the difference between `LoadClass` and `LoadClassWithOptions` but I think this is not the problem here. The uncommented lines correspond to what I understand from  the document clsguide.pdf  but it does not work.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

% my class file
\begin{filecontents}{baz.cls}
\PassOptionsToClass{fleqn}{article}
\ProcessOptions\relax
%\LoadClass[fleqn]{article}
\LoadClass{article}
%\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{baz} 
%\documentclass[fleqn]{baz} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation*}
    e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The confusion in this example is coming from the fact that it is really the `amsmath` package that needs to know about the `fleqn` option.  As it stands you are passing no options to `amsmath`.  One working set up would be:

`baz.sty`:

```
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[fleqn]{article}
\RequirePackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```

tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{baz} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]
\begin{equation*}
    e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Here you see additional options being passed on to the class, which is loaded additionally with `fleqn` option.  The package `amsmath` is loaded with the `fleqn` option too.  In this case, it may well be the package option is unnecessary, but this mimics the effect of

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Comment: Ok, thus it was a bad example ... Is my code right for a more standard options ? and how can I be sure that options added from the `documentclass` will overwrite options defined into the class file

Comment: The example is not bad - this is a common gotcha when converting a preamble to a class, you have to make sure appropriate options get passed down to appropriate packages.  For options that are only for the class, your example is fine (but the `\ProcessOptions` is redundant), but I would probably use the shorter syntax `\LoadClass[option]{class}`